# E-Commerce Mock App in Console

Tags: c#, console, linq, e-commerce

I have completed this E-Commerce Mock App in Console C# which I used object to store the data to apply some C# OOP and LINQ techniques. Since it is just a mock version, features are reduced to the minimum.

Any code review on coding style or code refactoring will be appreciated.

I have created 3 projects in this solution structure:

- `ECommerceDomainModelEntities` - poco classes
- `ECommerceLib` - library
- `ECommerceConsoleUI` - Console UI (Entry Point)

**ECommerceDomainModelEntities Project**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetails
{
    public int OrderDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int Customer_Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOrder { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

**ECommerceLib Project**

```
public static class Utility
{
    private static CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ms-MY");

    public static void PrintMessage(string text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public static string FormatAmount(this decimal amt)
    {
        return string.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", amt);
    }

    public static string ReadPassword()
    {
        string password = "";
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    return null;
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    return password;
                case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                    password = password.Substring(0, (password.Length - 1));
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                    break;
                default:
                    password += key.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write("*");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintDotAnimation(int timer = 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (var x = 0; x < timer; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**ECommerceConsoleUI Project**

```
public class eCommerce
{
private const decimal deliverCharges = 10.00M;
private List<Customer> validCustomers;
private readonly List<OrderDetails> shoppingCart;
private List<Product> productList;

public eCommerce()
{
    InitializeCustomerList();
    InitializeProductList();
    shoppingCart = new List<OrderDetails>();
    Console.Title = "Azada e-Commerce App";
}

public void Execute()
{
    var valid_Customer = Login();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"Login as {valid_Customer.FullName}");
        Console.WriteLine("\nAzada E-Commerce App");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Browse all products");
        Console.WriteLine("2. View shopping cart");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Logout");
        Console.Write("Enter your option: ");
        string opt = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (opt)
        {
            case "1":
                BrowseProducts();
                AddShoppingCart(valid_Customer);
                break;
            case "2":
                ViewShoppingCart(valid_Customer);
                break;
            case "3":
                Utility.PrintDotAnimation();
                valid_Customer = null;
                shoppingCart.Clear();
                Execute();
                break;
            default:
                Utility.PrintMessage("Invalid option.", ConsoleColor.Red);
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

private Customer Login()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var userInput = new Customer();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        userInput.Username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Password: ");
        userInput.Password = Utility.ReadPassword();

        var validCustomer = validCustomers
        .Where(c => c.Username.Equals(userInput.Username))
        .Where(c => c.Password.Equals(userInput.Password))
        .FirstOrDefault();

        if (validCustomer != null)
        {
            Utility.PrintDotAnimation();
            return validCustomer;
        }


        Utility.PrintMessage("\nInvalid username or password.", ConsoleColor.Red);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

private void InitializeCustomerList()
{
    validCustomers = new List<Customer>(){
        new Customer(){
            CustomerId = 1,
            Username = "john",
            Password = "john123",
            FullName = "John Wong",
            Email = "john@gmail.com",
            Address = "8, Jalan Emas, 58000, Kuala Lumpur."
            },
            new Customer(){
            CustomerId = 2,
            Username = "mike",
            Password = "mike123",
            FullName = "Mike Lee",
            Email = "mike@gmail.com",
            Address = "13, Jalan Api, 55100, Kuala Lumpur."
            }
    };
}

private void InitializeProductList()
{
    productList = new List<Product>() {
        new Product(){ Id = 2, ProductName = "MSI Laptop GL63 8RCS 058MY", UnitPrice = 2999.00M},
        new Product(){ Id = 5, ProductName = "MSI Laptop GL63 8RC 057MY", UnitPrice = 3799.00M},
        new Product(){ Id = 12, ProductName = "Logitech M330 Wireless Mouse", UnitPrice = 59.00M},
        new Product(){ Id = 13, ProductName = "Mechanical Keyboard with Backlight", UnitPrice = 160.00M},
        new Product(){ Id = 16, ProductName = "Dell Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo ", UnitPrice = 70.00M}
    };
}

private void BrowseProducts()
{
    Console.Clear();

    var table = new ConsoleTable("Product Id", "Product Name", "Unit Price");

    foreach (var product in productList)
        table.AddRow(product.Id, product.ProductName, Utility.FormatAmount(product.UnitPrice));


    table.Write();
}

private void AddShoppingCart(Customer valid_Customer)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the product ID you want to buy: ");
    int productId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var selectedProduct = productList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);

    if (selectedProduct == null)
    {
        Utility.PrintMessage("Product not found.", ConsoleColor.Red);
        return;
    }

    Console.Write("Enter quantity to buy: ");
    int quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var order = new OrderDetails();
    order.Customer_Id = valid_Customer.CustomerId;
    order.ProductId = productId;
    order.QuantityOrder = quantity;
    order.TotalAmount = quantity * selectedProduct.UnitPrice;

    shoppingCart.Add(order);
    Utility.PrintMessage($"{selectedProduct.ProductName} added into shopping cart.", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
}

private void ViewShoppingCart(Customer valid_Customer)
{
    Console.Clear();

    // inner join orderdetail and product.
    var shoppingCart2 = from s in shoppingCart
                        join p in productList on s.ProductId equals p.Id
                        select new { p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice, s.QuantityOrder, s.TotalAmount };
    var totalOrderAmount = 0M;
    totalOrderAmount = shoppingCart.Sum(s => s.TotalAmount);
    var table = new ConsoleTable("Product Name", "Price", "Quantity", "Total");

    if (shoppingCart2.ToList().Count == 0)
    {
        Utility.PrintMessage("Shopping cart is empty. Go to browse products.", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total Items in Shopping Cart: " + shoppingCart2.Count());
    foreach (var item in shoppingCart2)
        table.AddRow(item.ProductName, Utility.FormatAmount(item.UnitPrice), item.QuantityOrder, Utility.FormatAmount(item.TotalAmount));

    table.Options.EnableCount = false;
    table.Write();

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Delivery charges: " + Utility.FormatAmount(deliverCharges));
    Console.WriteLine("Total Order Amount: " + Utility.FormatAmount(totalOrderAmount + deliverCharges));
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Delivery Address: " + valid_Customer.Address);

    Console.WriteLine("\n1. Confirm order and proceed to make payment.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Clear shopping cart.");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Back.");
    Console.Write("Enter option: ");
    string opt2 = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (opt2)
    {
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("\nChoose payment method:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Cash on delivery (COD)");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Credit Card");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Online eBanking");
            Console.Write("Enter option: ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nRedirecting to payment gateway.");
            Utility.PrintDotAnimation();
            Console.WriteLine("Info: This E-Commerce simulation app ends here....");

            // You can send email to the customer upon payment.
            break;
        case "2":
            shoppingCart.Clear();
            Utility.PrintMessage("Shopping cart is empty. Go to browse products.", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            break;
        case "3":
            break;
        default:
            Utility.PrintMessage("Invalid option.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: We have asked you before to split UI from business logic: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224139/console-based-blackjack-in-c-follow-up. And you said you were going to follow-up on that advise, but you haven't. The problem with this code, is that it's one big convoluted code mess. There is no way to reuse your business logic with another UI or as dependency of another API. I would have hoped you would have addressed this by now :-(

Comment: Yeah, I still unable to split it yet. I also didn't create any Web API for it. Any other comment besides that?